# SSRS and SQL Server database on different server

Tags: sql, database, reporting-services

Is it possible to install SSRS and SQL Server database on separate servers, or should these two be installed on the same server?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any reason why SSRS couldn't be installed on a separate server - it just needs to have *access* to a SQL Server to store its two internal databases on - but that can definitely be another machine.... have you tried it?

Comment: From memory, I think you need to have separate licences for each machine a SQL component is installed on - definitely worth checking on.

Comment: One more point that hasn't been mentioned; with SQL Server Express edition there is another consideration - from MSDN:

"All data sources that provide data to reports must connect to SQL Server relational databases are that are installed on the local instance of SQL Server."

Effectively this means that if you have Express edition it's not really practical to have separate installations.

Comment: As Dave says, the technical limitation is different than the licensing problem. Installing SSRS on a separate server usually requires a full SQL Server license, so few installations are structured this way.

Answer (score 14):

In order to have Reporting Services on your application server, you would have to use a SQL-Server license. You can install just the Reporting Services section of SQLServer, but it is still technically part of the SQL Server application and requires a license for use on that processor(s).

So yes, you can install it on another server. 
Yes, you can install only the advanced services, but that still counts as full server., so it requires a full license.

Yes, you can install an Express Edition (with advanced services) on another server for free. 
But... the express edition SSRS can't access a non-localhost database (technical limitations of express & web edition). 
You can try to circumvent that with linked-servers, but you need to duplicate every used stored procedure, view, table etc., so it's an impractical mess.

The answer to your question is thus: **Technically, yes - but actually NO, not without another license**.
That extra-installation is gonna cost USD 1'000+ per month.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can install SSRS and a SQL Server database on different servers. While the default installation tries to install both, you can select to install them separately.

MSDN links:

[Considerations for Installing Reporting Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143736%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

[Installing SQL Server Reporting Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143736%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

From MSDN article [Considerations for Installing Reporting Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143736%28v=sql.100%29.aspx):

> Select Database Engine Services in the Feature Selection page to host
>   the report server databases. *Reporting Services requires a local or
>   remote instance of SQL Server 2005 or SQL Server 2008 Database Engine
>   to host the report server databases.* If you install an instance of the
>   Database Engine concurrently with Reporting Services, you can
>   eliminate a post-Setup task by installing the default configuration,
>   which creates and configures the report server databases
>   automatically. In addition to hosting the report server databases, SQL
>   Server relational databases can also be a source of data for reports
>   and models.

Comment: I'm trying to install SSRS 2008 R2 on a separate server to my SQL Server DB instance, but can't figure out how to do it. The SQL Server 2008 R2 installer won't let me install SSRS without installing a new instance of SQL Server, am I missing something? I know SSRS can use a SQL instance on a different server for its backend databases, but can you install it without a local instance or will there always be a redundant SQL Server instance on the server where SSRS is installed?

Answer (score 3):

You could install SSRS in a new server, but to do so you would need a new license for this other server.

From Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Licensing Guide:

*"The software components of a single SQL Server 2014 license cannot be separated for use in more than one OSE. If these components are running on a server other than the main database server, then an additional license is required for each additional OSE in which they are installed. For example, if the SQL Server DB is deployed in one OSE and SQL Server RS is deployed in another, both OSEs must be fully licensed for SQL Server 2014 accordingly."*

Link to download the guide:

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=230678